# How to break this string correctly

Tags: php, string

I have strings that have the following pattern. `Some text on some more text before some text`.

How do I find

- the position of the word "before" and remove it with anything after it,
- and the position of the word " on " and remove it with anything before it?

Comment: Are the words `before` and `on` guaranteed to only ever occur once in your subjects?

Comment: @fireeyedboy yes, only once, but only with spaces around them like ` on `

Comment: And do the spaces around them need to be removed as well? Or only the ones around `on`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regular expressions are overkill for this. Just do a substring from where you find "on" to where you find "before":

```
$str = 'Some text on some more text before some text';

// Find " on "
$start = strpos($str, " on ");

// Check for errors
// Note the 3 ='s
if($start === FALSE) {
    // Error occurred, do something
}
$start += 4; // Go after "on"

// Find " before "
$end = strpos($str, " before ", $start);

// Check for errors
// Note the 3 ='s
if($end === FALSE) {
    // Error occurred, do something
}

// Get just the part we want
$length = $end - $start;
$result = substr($str, $start, $end - $start);
```

Comment: Failed at Console on test before other test.

Comment: $str = 'Console text on text before text'; $res will  "sole text on text"(finded on word cinsole), not full word.

Comment: @RiaD I added the spaces around the search words

Answer (score 2):

```
preg_match('~\bon\b(.+)\bbefore\b~',$text,$match);
//use $match[1]; e.g $text=$match[1];
```

Comment: Uh, I thought it was correct, but it needs delimiters, and parentheses around `.+`. Then use `$match[1]` to grab the text.

Answer (score 1):

consider using regular expressions:

```
$text= "Some text on some more text before some text";
$pattern = '/^.* on(.*)before.*$/';

preg_match($pattern, $text, $matches);
if($matches) {
    print $matches[1];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php

$string = 'Some text on some more text before some text';

$newString = preg_replace('/(.*)on(.*)before(.*)/', '$2', $string);

echo $newString;
```

Regex: http://regexr.com?2uqq7

PHP demo: http://codepad.org/uXBL8IaA

Answer (score 1):

```
    $var="Some text on some more text before some text";
preg_match('/\bon\b(.*)\bbefore\b/',$var,$match);
//Edit: You can use `(.+)` too if, by any chance, there is no text between 'on' and 'before'.
print_r ($match);
//$match[1] has "some more text"
```

Is this what you want?

and as for the position thing, you can `echo strrpos($var, " on ");` if I'm getting this correctly (as you said in the comment that "on" has spaces around it. `echo strrpos($var, "before");` too, this will return the position of the first character.

Answer (score -5):

```
$str = 'Some text on some more text before some text';
$str = str_replace(array('on','before'), '', $str);
```

Comment: That just removes the words "on" and "before" from $str.  The resulting text would be "Some text some more text some text"